# Convert Hashtable to System.Version

Tags: powershell

In powershell is there a way to convert a hashtable to System.Version, the error I'm getting is Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Version".

Example
in my foreach loop, I add two variables a key and a value to dbDictionary

> $dbDictionary.Add($dbChangesfiles, $line)

I then want to turn that dbDictionary into a System.Version so I can reference it against two other variables I have converted to System.Version.

> $dbDictionaryAsVersion = [System.Version]$dbDictionary

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with a direct cast. You need to be specific and reference the dictionary item that contains the version value:

```
PS> $dbDictionary = @{key1='1.2'; key2='3.4'}
PS> [System.Version]$dbDictionary['key1']

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      2      -1     -1
```

If the version consists of all keys:

```
PS> [System.Version]($dbDictionary.Values -join '.')

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      2      3      4
```

Comment: Note that (absent [`[ordered]` in PSv3](http://arcanecode.com/2012/06/04/powershell-v3-ordered-hashtables/)) values in hastables are not guaranteed to be in the order you add them, so a `-join` on `@{ A = 1; B = 2 }` may return either `1.2` or `2.1`.

Comment: Correct, but the default formatting of System.Version overrides that.